# How to refresh DataTable and keep position

Tags: jquery, datatables

Is there a way to refresh the jQuery DataTable and keep the current page?

I'm using `fnReloadAjax` method to reload data from its AJAX datasource, but the problem is that I loose currently selected page and now I have to navigate again to the needed one.

Answer (score 1):

Try passing this parameters to `fnReloadAjax`, like :

```
Table.fnReloadAjax(null, null, true); // user paging is not reset on reload
```

*Don't forget to change 'Table' to your table var name. I hope it works, thanks !*

Comment: @Eugen Did you used any `Redraw()` function with `fnAjaxReload` ? try removing other redraw function because `fnReloadAjax` has a standing redraw option _(true in the third parameter)_.

Comment: Didn't use anything else, just fnReloadAjax(null,null, null, true); It actually has 4 parameters. But as I can see from the code, it expects me to send the current page in the first parameters. Not sure how.